# Fill diagonal of a 3D NumPy array by values from a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, diagonal

I am trying to fill a 3D NumPy array with the values of a 2D array using the numpy.fill_diagonal function. Both arrays have the same number of rows and columns. However, it results in an error `ValueError: All dimensions of input must be of equal length`

Below is an example of what I tried to do and what I am expecting to have

```
A = [[[0 1 1 1]
      [1 0 1 1]
      [1 1 0 1]
      [1 1 1 0]]
        
      [[0 1 1 1]
       [1 0 1 1]
       [1 1 0 1]
       [1 1 1 0]]]

B = [[1 4 2 3]
     [3 1 4 2]]

# Actual array shapes
A.shape (35,4,4)
B.shape (35,4)

numpy.fill_diagonal(A, B)

Expected result:
    [[[1 1 1 1]
      [1 4 1 1]
      [1 1 2 1]
      [1 1 1 3]]
        
      [[3 1 1 1]
      [1 1 1 1]
      [1 1 4 1]
      [1 1 1 2]]]
```

I have tried to reshape the 2D array to a 3D shape as follows

```
numpy.fill_diagonal(A, B[:,:,numpy.newaxis])
```

But I still got the same error

Comment: `fill_diagonal` docs says that if `B` is `If array-like, the flattened `val` is written along the diagonal, repeating if necessary to fill all diagonal entries.`.  So reshaping does nothing for you.

Comment: Show the full error message, with actual code.  I can't reproduce it.  Given a (3,3,3), `A`, I can, at most insert 3 diagonal values.

Comment: Digging further into `fill_diagonal` code (it's python), I see more clearly that `All dimensions of input must be of equal length` is complaining about the dimensions of `A`.  Your real `A` must not be (3,3,3)!

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, sorry, I just tried to give an example with mocked data. Actually, I have a 3d array with shape (35, 4, 4) and a 2d array with shape (35, 4). I edited the question's example code to better explain the problem.

Comment: I need to fill each diagonal inside the 3d array with each value in the same order as they appear in the 2d array. I hope that the edited example will help you to understand my issue

Comment: clearly `fill_diagonal` is not the function  to do this.  It expects a (n,n,n) shape array, and puts `n` values in its 3d diagonal.  Sounds like you only read the function name.

Answer (score 1):

`fill_diagonal` talks about using `diag_indices`.  Specifically `np.diag_indices(3,ndim=3)` produces the 3d indices for the 3 diag values that it sets.

Instead let's get the 2d indices:

```
In [266]: I,J=np.diag_indices(3,2)
In [267]: I,J
Out[267]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```

Then with a 3d array:

```
In [268]: A = np.zeros((3,3,3))

In [269]: A[:,I,J]
Out[269]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

selects a (3,3) block.  Then setting them with a (3,3):

```
In [270]: A[:,I,J]=np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
In [271]: A
Out[271]: 
array([[[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 2., 0.],
        [0., 0., 3.]],

       [[4., 0., 0.],
        [0., 5., 0.],
        [0., 0., 6.]],

       [[7., 0., 0.],
        [0., 8., 0.],
        [0., 0., 9.]]])
```

That's the diagonal filling pattern you want.

Read the docs of functions like `fill_diagonal` carefully.  And if there are confusing bits, see it's written in Python, so you can better figure out what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, without fancy indexing, but with strides play.

```py
# My mre. I prefer to create array that way. Yours are not reusable (you ommited commas and stuff)
# Plus, it is preferable to have very distinguishable number, or else, I
# may end up, for example, copying the same layer again and again, without
# noticing it, since they are all the same
A=np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
B=np.arange(30,39).reshape(3,3)

# Now we want diagonals of A replaced by B
# The trick for that is to create another view of A, showing only its diagonals
s1,s2,s3=A.strides
DiagA = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A, shape=B.shape, strides=(s1,s2+s3))

# And change the values of this view with those of B
DiagA[:]=B

# Since the data used by DiagA and A are the same (DiagA is a view, not
# a copy), this alter also A
```

The tricky part is obviously the `DiagA=...` line. But it worth understanding it, because it helps very often when you understand what it does.
What this does is creating a view of A (so same data as A), with a shape begin the shape of B (so 3,3). And Whose elements are accessed with the given stride.

Stride of a ND-array `arr`, is the tuple (s1,s2,...,sN) such as the address of element `arr[i1,i2,...,iN]` is the address of `arr[0,0,...0]` + `i1*s1+i2*s2+...+iN*sN`.

So strides (s1,s2,s3) of `A` is such as address of `A[i,j,k]` is address of 1st element `A[0,0,0]` + `i*s1+j*s2+k*s3`.

And stride of (s1',s2') the view `DiagA` is such as address of `DiagA[i,j]` is address of `DiagA[0,0]` + `s1'*i+s2'*j`. Here I've tuned strides so that `s1'=s1` and `s2'=s2+s3`. So address of `Diag[i,j]` is the address of `Diag[0,0]` + `s1*i+s2*j+s3*j`. Which happens, since it is the same data (same `[0...0]` element, to be also the address of `A[i,j,j]`.

So `DiagA[i,j]` is just a view to `A[i,j,j]`.

And that view is read-write. So I can `DiagA[:]=B` to modify those `A[i,j,j]`.

The beauty of it, is that it cost nothing (the `DiagA[:]=B` cost, of course, what cost the copy of a 2D-array on another 2D-array). But the creation of `DiagA` itself cost nothing. No memory, and no CPU (or almost so). It is just a tweak of the stride, a one or two change of the metadata, that's all.

Tbh, it takes really big array before it worth it. Hpaulj's method is twice faster for 3x3x3 array. For 100x100x100 arrays, it is roughly the same. And it is only with 200x200x200 arrays that, at last, I reach a point where my method is faster (90 μs vs 120 μs. And when you think about it, both are really fast, considering that we are talking arrays of 8000000 elements. Because both, essentially just deal with the copy of 40000 elements of them)